# Python Send known bytes

Tags: python, sockets

I want to send a stream of known `bytes` over the network, such as `0020ff00`, but I want to use other method beside concatenation of `char` symbols.
Can you provide me with another, more elegant method?
Thanks

```
def send_connect_request(sock):
    print('Sending connect request...')
    sock.send('' + chr(2) + chr(0) + chr(0) + chr(0) + chr(255) + chr(0))   
    # sock.shutdown(1)
```

change to

```
def send_connect_request(sock):
    print('Sending connect request...')
    sock.send(0x0002ff00)       
    # sock.shutdown(1)
```

Comment: Python 2 or 3??

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga python 3

Comment: ... um, `sock.send('' + chr(2) + chr(0) + chr(0) + chr(0) + chr(255) + chr(0))` isn't failing with a `TypeError`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga not at all

Comment: is this a `socket.socket` object, from the `socket` standard library module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the bytes, use a `bytes` literal:

```
sock.send(b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00')
```

If you really don't want to type out all the escape-sequences, use the `bytes` constructor with a list of `int`s:

```
sock.send(bytes([2,0,0,0,255,0]))
```